# Mission Control on Mac with multiple Screens

Tags: mission-control

I have an issue how Mission Control selects pro-actively the focused app/window on a monitor B when chosing the app in Monitor A.

Setup

- For simplicity let's say I have two monitors, A and B.
- Both have one desktop/workspace each
- both have two app/windows open (not full size)

  - Monitor A has a Chrome instance and an IDE instance
  - Monitor B aswell has a Chrome instance and an IDE instance

I have now

- on A: IDE in foreground (Chrome behind that)
- on B: IDE in foreground (Chrome behind that)

I want to

- navigate to Chrome on B using Mission control

Steps

- open Mission Control (for exammple with mouse or Shortcut)
- that brings the birds-eye view of all open apps/windows
- I click Chrome on monitor B

The issue

- **when I select Chrome on B sometimes / occasionally Chrome also opens on A**

This "sometimes" behavior drives me nuts. At least, can I understand this "sometimes" behavior? Anything to make it consistent? I don't want to re-focus apps on A, when I select on B.

Comment: Are all IDE windows the same app? Also what does one desktop mean on each screen?

Comment: The IDEs are the same app. Other apps behave the same (2x Chrome, 2x Finder, just tested). Desktop: in Mission Control on top there is a list of all workspaces. They are called "Desktop 1", "Desktop 2". For simplicity I only use one Desktop per screen.

Comment: This has been an inconsistency since High Sierra. Before that, if you brought an app to the font, all windows would *always* come to the front. Since then, it's depended on how you call the app [mostly]. If you click the app in the Dock, all will come forward; if you click any single window, only that one will comes forward… if you're lucky :\ It's just been a mess for a long time.